# Mulltiple vmware-hostd process running

Tags: vmware-esx, vmware-vsphere

I have an ESX4 server that disconnected itself from virtualcenter. I went in and ran "service mgmt-vmware restart" and the command hung for about 3 hours, I eventually had to go in and try to kill the vmware-hostd by issuing the kill -9 command. After that I restarted the mgmt-vmware service however could not get the server to connect to either the VIC or VC server. I issued the "service mgmt-vmware restart" command again and it restarted the service, however, I noticed that it did not kill the vmware-hostd process it just created a new one. I've tried stopping the mgmt-vmware service, which say's it works, however, it doesn't kill the process and will create a new one when you start the service back. I've tried running kill -9 against the PID's and no success.

I'm stuck with multiple hostd process' and no connectivity to VC. I have about 12 running VM's on this server and they are all running. I really do not want to reboot the server. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into just about the same exact problem on an ESX 3.5 box recently.  Please note my instructions are for 3.5 due to not having a 4 server around right now. the commands shouldn't be too far off

*you are probably going to have to reboot the host*

- check for errors in /var/log/hostd.log
- Check for errors in /var/log/vmkernel

For me my sand dropped out from under the server for about 2 seconds while it was in the middle of a vmotion - lemmie tell you it doesn't like that.

if you do have to reboot you can try the following commands to attempt a clean shutdown **if you have a current version of vmware tools installed**

Get all of the running hosts and the path to their vmx files

`vmware-cmd -l`

You'll get something like:

```
/vmfs/volumes/48221444-8ab49b9a-7e2d-001d096881c9/ASTTest/ASTTest.vmx
/vmfs/volumes/47a0b49f-3e7bd396-9091-001d096881cb/TestMachine/TestMachine.vmx
```

`vmware-cmd <path_to_vmx> stop soft`

and example would be:

```
vmware-cmd /vmfs/volumes/47a0b49f-3e7bd396-9091-001d096881cb/TestMachine/TestMachine.vmx stop soft
```

Once everything is down, go ahead and reboot the host.